# how to make a page in customer my account in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

i want a tab with upload from in customer my account in magento 1.9.2,Can anybody guide me how to make it step by step.

Answer (score 3):

First, create a custom module. You can find a lot of examples on [creating custom Magento modules](https://www.google.com.np/?gws_rd=cr&ei=k0PQVfiBCYmcugTj0b64DQ#q=create%20custom%20module%20magento).

After you have your custom module created, you can follow the steps below to `add custom tab on customer account section`.

1. Add following code in your module's layout xml file (**app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/yourmodule.xml**)

   ```
   <customer_account>        
       <reference name="customer_account_navigation">           
           <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="yourmodule">
               <name>viewyourmodule</name>
               <path>yourmodule/customer/view</path>
               <label>Yourmodule</label>
           </action>
       </reference>
   </customer_account> 

   <yourmodule_customer_view>
       <update handle="customer_account"/>
       <reference name="content">
           <block type="yourmodule/customer" name="view.yourmodule" template="yourmodule/customer/view.phtml"/>
       </reference>
   </yourmodule_customer_view>
   ```
2. Create a controller class (**app/code/local/YourNamespace/Yourmodule/controllers/CustomerController.php**)

   ```
   class YourNamespace_Yourmodule_CustomerController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
   {   
       /**
        * Checking if user is logged in or not
        * If not logged in then redirect to customer login
        */
       public function preDispatch()
       {
           parent::preDispatch();

           if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this)) {
               $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);

           // adding message in customer login page
           Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
                   ->addSuccess(Mage::helper('yourmodule')->__('Please sign in or create a new account'));
           }
       }           

       /**
        * View Your Module
        */
       public function viewAction()
       {                   
           $this->loadLayout();        
           $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Your Module Title'));     
           $this->renderLayout();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a Block class which you might need in future (**app/code/local/YourNamespace/Yourmodule/Block/Customer.php**)

   ```
   class YourNamespace_YourModule_Block_Customer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
   {
       // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
   }
   ```
4. Create template file to show your custom content (**app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/yourmodule/customer/view.phtml**)

   ```
   Write about your content
   ```

Now, you should be able to see the custom tab on customer my account section. When you click on that tab, then your template file content will be displayed.

**Source:** [**Magento: Add new tab to Customer Account Section**](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-add-new-tab-to-customer-account-frontend/)